# change the default HTML code from HTML 4.01 to HTML 5 in Eclipse EE

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I just started learning Java EE, and I'm using Eclipse as an IDE.

When I create a new JSP file, I get the HTML code for HTML 4.01.

Isn't there any way change the default HTML code from HTML 4.01 to HTML 5 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of cause,
click on "Window" => "Preferences" and scroll down to "Web" in the left Frame, then choose there "JSP Files" => "Editor" => "Templates" and edit your JSP Template.

[image]
Patrick :)